# Sharing on WhatsApp in iOS 9.0

Tags: swift, ios9

I m new in iOS development and i want to integrate WhatsApp sharing in my app in ios 9.0 . i have searched various methods but they all are depreciated in ios 9.0

Can anyone suggest me updated method for the same,

```
@IBAction func whattsappInvite(sender: UIButton) 
{
    let urlString = "Hello Friends, Sharing some data here... !"
    let urlStringEncoded = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    let url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded!)")

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted compiles without error or warning in Xcode 7.1 targeting iOS 9.1. Also, looking at the documentation, I do not see any deprecation notices. So .... ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share with Whatsapp, you can use your code or this one as a base :

```
var whatsappURL:NSURL?= NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL)) {

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL) 
    }
```

**None of these methods are deprecated in iOS 9.0**.

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed the canOpenURL method on iOS 9. Apps which are checking for URL Schemes have to declare these Schemes as it is submitted to Apple. Else canOpenURL returns false.

Add whatsapp field in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist of your app.

Or try using whatsapp share extension